# How to avoid selected values to be copied to the next row in Vuetify

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuetify.js

I have used [Vuetify DataTables](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/data-tables), in that `DataTable` I have multiple rows along with `save button` above the table.

Inside the `Datatable`,

- `textfield`
- `select`

When I write something in the `text field` and select the values from drop down `select` and click the save `button`, that row is moved from one page to another page.

**Problem**

Whatever selected from the drop-down and written in the `textfield` is get copied to the next row or you can say it is there for the next row which occupies the place for the moved row.

I want that it should not be there, i.e the `textfield` should be blank and no value will be selected for the next row.

**Code**:

```
<v-card v-if="resultedvalue">
   <v-card-title>             
       <v-text-field
          append-icon="search"
          v-bind:label="$t('message.search')"
          single-line
          hide-details
          v-model="search"
        ></v-text-field>
   </v-card-title>

         <v-data-table             
            v-bind:headers="headers"
            v-bind:items="resultedvalue"               
            select-all
            v-bind:search="search"
            v-bind:pagination.sync="pagination"         
            class="elevation-1"
          >           
           <template slot="headers" slot-scope="props">
             <tr>                     
              <th v-for="header in props.headers" 
                  :key="header.text"
                  :class="['column sortable', pagination.descending ? 'desc' : 'asc', 
                   header.value === pagination.sortBy ? 'active' : '']"
                   @click="changeSort(header.value)" 
                  v-bind:align="header.align"
              > 
                 {{ $t(header.text) }}
              <v-icon v-if="header.text.length > 0">arrow_upward</v-icon>
             </th>
             </tr>
            </template>
            <template slot="items" slot-scope="props">
            <tr :active="props.selected" >                  
                <td class="text-xs-left">{{ props.item.xyz}}</td>
                <td class="text-xs-left">{{ props.item.abc}}</td>
                <td class="text-xs-left">
                   <div>
                      {{props.item.ied}}<br>
                      {{props.item.dfshj}}&nbsp;
                      {{props.item.dfgnu}}&nbsp;
                   </div>
                </td>
                <td class="text-xs-left">
                   <div @click="show_dialog(props.item.dsfg,props.item.dfg)" 
                        style= "cursor: pointer" 
                        title="Click here to see details"
                    >
                        {{props.item.dfgfd}}
                   </div>
                </td>
                <td class="text-xs-left">
                  <v-text-field v-model="props.item.testvalue"></v-text-field>
                </td>
                <td class="text-xs-left">
                     <v-text-field
                        name="input-1"
                        label="Answer"
                        v-on:change="change_answer(props.item,$event)"
                        rows="1"
                        textarea
                    ></v-text-field>
                </td>
                <td class="text-xs-left">
                   <v-select
                        v-bind:items="props.item.valuetobeselect" 
                        v-on:change="changed(props.item,$event)"                        
                        label="Select"                          
                        single-line
                        bottom>
                    </v-select>
                </td>

             </tr>
          </template>

        </v-data-table>
```

**Before Save**
[image: Before Save]

**After Save**
[image: After Save]

Change Event Methods:-

```
  changed: function(element, item) {            
        element.somevalues = item;
        this.selected_element= element;
    },
    change_answer:function(element,item){
        var currentdate =  new Date().toJSON();
        element.somevalue = item;
        element.somevalue1 = currentdate;       
    },
```

For the save button it is just calling the rest service and once the rest service is executed it called the initialized method which initializes  the table .

Comment: You want the next rows to be blank after save If I don't misunderstood your question?  Also include your methods in the code.

Comment: @gil Yes correct I upload the method